# Postgres aggregate with case

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.6

I have a some query that returns a table "code_1"(id - distinct).

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         id          |       status     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |         true     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |         true     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         false    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |         true     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |         false    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Based on the data .. I want to get the following table ("code_2")

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|     id              |     status       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |      include     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |      include     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          3          |      partial     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          4          |      exclude     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

if the id is repeated status is partial, else status = status from code_1 table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, use aggregation:

```
select id,
       (case when min(status) = max(status) and min(status) then 'Include'
             when min(status) = max(status) and not min(status) then 'Exclude'
             else 'Partial'
        end) as status
from t
group by id;
```

Or, using boolean aggregation functions:

```
select id,
       (case when bool_and(status) then 'Include'
             when bool_or(status) then 'Partial'
             else 'Exclude'
        end) as status
from t
group by id;
```